# Read a text file in target folder in karate framework

Tags: cucumber, karate

i wanted to read data from a file in the target folder.. path of file:-  /api_automation/target/a.txt
And the file in which i want to read a.txt file has path /api_automation/src/test/java/com/jcapi/functional/readhere.feature

I tried reading file a.txt in target folder from read function and it was giving me file not found error